# PDAnnotationTextMarkup missing when rendering a pdf page to image PDFBox Java

Tags: java, pdfbox, pdfrenderer

I have code written using PDFBox API that highlights the words in a PDF but when I convert highlighted PDF pages to images, then whatever I have highlighted gets disappeared from the image.

Below screenshot is with highlighted text, for highlighting I have used PDFBox's PDAnnotationTextMarkup class:

[Highlighted PDF Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1N4p.png)

Below is the image after converting the pdf page to image:

[Highlighted PDF Page Image after converting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a7Dk.png)

Below is the code I have used for converting PDF to Image:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(pdfFilename));
PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
int pageCounter = 0;
for (PDPage page : document.getPages())
{
   BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(pageCounter, 300, ImageType.RGB);

   ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, pdfFilename + "-" + (pageCounter++) + ".png", 300);
}
document.close();
```

Please suggest what is wrong here, why PDFRenderer not able to take PDF page image along with the highlighted red box.

Below is the code I used to highlight the text in PDF:

```
private void highlightText(String pdfFilePath, String highlightedPdfFilePath) {
    try {
        // Loading an existing document
        
        File file = new File(highlightedPdfFilePath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file = new File(pdfFilePath);
        }
        
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
        
        // extended PDFTextStripper class
        PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextHighlighter();
        
        // Get number of pages
        int number_of_pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().getCount();

        // The method writeText will invoke an override version of
        // writeString
        Writer dummy = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
        stripper.writeText(document, dummy);
        
        // Print collected information
        System.out.println("tokenStream:::"+tokenStream);
        System.out.println("tokenStream size::"+tokenStream.size());
        System.out.println("coordinates size::"+coordinates.size());

        double page_height;
        double page_width;
        double width, height, minx, maxx, miny, maxy;
        int rotation;
        
        // scan each page and highlitht all the words inside them
        for (int page_index = 0; page_index < number_of_pages; page_index++) {
            // get current page
            PDPage page = document.getPage(page_index);
            
            // Get annotations for the selected page
            List<PDAnnotation> annotations = page.getAnnotations();

            // Define a color to use for highlighting text
            PDColor red = new PDColor(new float[] { 1, 0, 0 }, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE);

            // Page height and width
            page_height = page.getMediaBox().getHeight();
            page_width = page.getMediaBox().getWidth();
            // Scan collected coordinates
            for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++) {
                if (!differencePgaeNumber.contains(page_index)) {
                    differencePgaeNumber.add(page_index);
                }
                // if the current coordinates are not related to the current
                // page, ignore them
                if ((int) coordinates.get(i)[4] != (page_index + 1))
                    continue;
                else {
                    // get rotation of the page...portrait..landscape..
                    rotation = (int) coordinates.get(i)[7];

                    // page rotated of 90degrees
                    if (rotation == 90) {
                        height = coordinates.get(i)[5];
                        width = coordinates.get(i)[6];
                        width = (page_height * width) / page_width;

                        // define coordinates of a rectangle
                        maxx = coordinates.get(i)[1];
                        minx = coordinates.get(i)[1] - height;
                        miny = coordinates.get(i)[0];
                        maxy = coordinates.get(i)[0] + width;
                    } else // i should add here the cases -90/-180 degrees
                    {
                        height = coordinates.get(i)[5];
                        minx = coordinates.get(i)[0];
                        maxx = coordinates.get(i)[2];
                        miny = page_height - coordinates.get(i)[1];
                        maxy = page_height - coordinates.get(i)[3] + height;
                    }
                    
                    // Add an annotation for each scanned word
                    PDAnnotationTextMarkup txtMark = new PDAnnotationTextMarkup(
                            PDAnnotationTextMarkup.SUB_TYPE_HIGHLIGHT);
                    txtMark.setColor(red);
                    txtMark.setConstantOpacity((float) 0.3); // 30%
                                                                // transparent
                    PDRectangle position = new PDRectangle();
                    position.setLowerLeftX((float) minx);
                    position.setLowerLeftY((float) miny);
                    position.setUpperRightX((float) maxx);
                    position.setUpperRightY((float) ((float) maxy + height));
                    txtMark.setRectangle(position);

                    float[] quads = new float[8];
                    quads[0] = position.getLowerLeftX(); // x1
                    quads[1] = position.getUpperRightY() - 2; // y1
                    quads[2] = position.getUpperRightX(); // x2
                    quads[3] = quads[1]; // y2
                    quads[4] = quads[0]; // x3
                    quads[5] = position.getLowerLeftY() - 2; // y3
                    quads[6] = quads[2]; // x4
                    quads[7] = quads[5]; // y5
                    txtMark.setQuadPoints(quads);
                    txtMark.setContents(tokenStream.get(i).toString());
                    
                    annotations.add(txtMark);
                }
            }
        }

        // Saving the document in a new file
        File highlighted_doc = new File(highlightedPdfFilePath);
        
        document.save(highlighted_doc);
        document.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the code that you used to create the annotation. Did you call constructAppearance()?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Edited my answer with highlighted code. I did not call constructAppearance() but where should I call it? with the annotation?

Comment: Yes, so call `txtMark.constructAppearances(document)`.

Comment: I just tried this, getting this error "The method constructAppearances(PDDocument) is undefined for the type PDAnnotationTextMarkup"

my dependency version: 
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
   <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.22</version>
  </dependency>

it seems there is no method as constructAppearances() defined for annotation.

Comment: Maybe you have several versions in your pom.xml file? The method is there.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Yes you were correct, after removing dependencies of other pdf compare tools such as pdfutil, pdf-compare etc. it worked. I also had to add one more dependency named "pdfbox-tools" for ImageIOUtils.

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
   <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.22</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thanks it is working now, I am getting the marked texts in the image.

Comment: Does this only work for Windows? If so, you should add an edit to the title.

Comment: @JohnGlen it should work in any OS. If it doesn't, then you have a different problem, please create a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct the visual appearance of the annotation with this call:

```
txtMark.constructAppearances(document);
```